# How to have plain MongoDB in Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and want to use the MEAN stack. I want to use MongoDB but some add-ons like MongoLab or MongoHQ. I believe it should be possible to install the plain MongoDB for my app. After all, we are installing other frameworks and libraries. Could anyone advice me on that?

Answer (score -1):

Heroku being an ephemeral file system, this may not be possible. This is the reason, we need add-ons or other database services. If any other platforms or service allows the installation of MongoDB, then probably you can link this database to your Heroku...!

That's what I understood from the representative of Heroku...!